# ROR how to link_to to the right link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a new project on rails and I have the class providers.
I made a new erb form file (called edit_info.erb) to edit some of the providers info.

I can't send a link to this page.
I tried -

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Information', edit_info_provider_path(@provider) %>
```

and a few more but nothing works.

Comment: change your erb file to edit_info.html.erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ rake routes
```

Run this command to see the route names.

If your page isn't listed, probably you'll want to add a new route on `config/routes.rb`.

Comment: Great! thanks.Just one thing - i dont see it there. maybe I didnt build the file in the proper way. I just build a new file into the providers folder. Should i make it in another way?

Comment: Soory man but how do i do that? what lines should i enter to routes.rb? Thanks

Comment: I don't know how your application is structured, but usually you just need to add a simple line like `get "info/provider"`. However I would recommend to generate a new controller, that automagically creates all the necessary. Try to run this: `$ rails generate controller providers info`

Answer (score 0):

If you use Rails scaffolding it will create RESTful routes and all the other stuff for you. Probably best to use scaffolding if this is your first Rails project, will get you off on a good footing.

I recommend you use the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) as your first port of call when learning to use Rails.